# Inserting multiple rows through a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Actually I want to insert multiple rows to a table.
The Structure of the table is

```
Create Table tbl_username
(id int  autoincrement,
username varchar(100),
Primary key(id))
```

and I tried to insert multiple rows like

```
Declare @s as varchar(100)
set @s='(''name1''),(''name2'')'
insert into tbl_username(username)values @s;
```

but I get the output as

```
id        username
1         (''name1''),(''name2'')
```

Actually the required output for me is

```
id          username
1           name1
2           name2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dynamic SQL

```
Declare @s as varchar(100)
Declare @sql as varchar(max)
set @s='(''name1''),(''name2'')'
set @sql = 'insert into tbl_username(username) values ' + @s;

execute(@sql);
```

However I would avoid dynamic SQL where possible.
The standard way to do it if your values are not in a variable is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_username(username) values ('name1'),('name2')
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO tbl_username(username) values ('name1')
INSERT INTO tbl_username(username) values ('name2')
```

If possible, opt for one of the above instead of the dynamic option originally mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @lock but how can i Execute two sql statements in a execute method or should I use two Execute methods like execute(@sql); and execute(@sql1)

Comment: Is recommending concatenation to form SQL queries really a good idea? I mean, it works in this simplistic example but it already requires quote juggling (10 quotes for 2 strings!) and is liable to break down on any value already including a quote should that `s` come from concatenation itself.

Comment: It's not how I would do it.. I would avoid dynamic sql however the question showed a variable already with the two rows as a string so my answer is based off an assumption that perhaps the data is getting passed in that way from another system possibly out of the ops control.

Answer (score 4):

```
insert into tbl_username(username)values ('name1'),('name2'),.....;
```

Here because username is of type varchar so it's considering @s as single value and inserting it in one row.

Comment: @RajaYuvi right, this is another way of doing it. there is no need to prepare two separate query string here and then execute.

Comment: @RajaYuvi: Please backup this statement. How is Lock's answer better when it's open to SQL Injection and requires fiddling with quotes?

Answer (score 2):

The below logic makes use of `substring` feature:

```
DECLARE @s as varchar(100), @Delimiter VARCHAR(1)

SET @s = 'name1,name2'
SET @Delimiter = ','

DECLARE @Position INT, @ListItem VARCHAR(MAX)

WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @s) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Position  = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @s)  
        SELECT @ListItem = SUBSTRING(@s, 1, @Position-1)

        INSERT INTO tbl_username 
            SELECT @ListItem

        SELECT @s = SUBSTRING(@s, @Position+1, LEN(@s)-@Position)
    END

INSERT INTO tbl_username 
    Select @s

SELECT * FROM tbl_username
```

Please try: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0f76/1/0